# How does Python recognise that .get should return every key without passing any parameters?

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

I am currently using this for loop to sort a dictionary's (used as a hashmap) values in descending order, then append these keys to a list:

```
hashmap = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1}
ans = []
for v in sorted(hashmap, key=hashmap.get, reverse=True):
    ans.append(v)
```

This does return me the correct answer, however I do not understand the `hashmap.get` call.

From what I understand the `dict.get` method has the required parameter *keyname*, and so should cause an error if none is passed. Is it that the keyword `key` is automatically extracting all keys from this call?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `hashmap.get` doesn't call `.get`. Try `x = hashmap.get` then `print(x)`, what do you see? What is the value?

Comment: It's not so much about how `dict.get` works but rather about how `sorted` works with a `key` parameter. Yes, `dict.get` expects a parameter, but that parameter will be given to it by `sorted`. That's what `sorted` does.

Comment: Try `sorted(hashmap, key=print)`